# how to get exact focal length for an image on android?

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I need to find the focal length of an image on run time.
The information available in the image metadata (EXIF) contains the camera's focal length, which is not the exact information as these are subject to change per image(due to autofocus).
I tried to dig into the Android camera and autofocus API with no luck.

Comment: If you know the camera that you are using, you can get the focal length from it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getFocalLength()

Comment: This will give the focal length of the camera assuming the object at an infinite (long) distance. But, if an object present closer then the auto-focus algo of the camera comes into the picture(and changes the focal length). i require focal length for the 2nd scenario.